# Is there a way to add a custom validation parameter to TokenValidationParameters in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I'm setting a new Jwt token authorization system (for authentication I use windows authentication). **I want to know if there is a way to add a custom *TokenValidationParameters*** in order to validate a token's stamp (AKA, if the token is not outdated) which I get from a db.

In the token itself I have stored some basic data about the user and a unique stamp. **Every time the user send a request to the server, I want to validate if the token's stamp match the stamp in the database** (meanning the token is up to date).

I want to note, I do not wish to add a custom claim or policy and check that policy on the controllers, Because i want to add this behavior to each request that has been sent to the server, and to send 401 before the authorization attributes of the requested controller has been checked

```
    // Get the latest user stamp from the db
    var stamp = db.users(u => u.id = id).FirstOrDefault()?.Stamp;

    var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "mydomain,com",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)),   

        // is that possible?
        // validatestamp = true,
        // validStamp = stamp
    };
```

Comment: Why not add those things as claims in the JWT?

Comment: Because I wish to check if the token's stamp is up to date, not if it exists on the token (because it always will be exist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have custom validation of a JWT bearer token early in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724525/how-to-have-custom-validation-of-a-jwt-bearer-token-early-in-the-pipeline)